# I have a code which works but how can ı make it more elegant

Tags: c#, console

simply it writes the string value in title format and centered but is there a way that use less for loop or use for loops nested and write a funciton for spaces so ı dont have to write same thing 3 times
(music is just for fun)
(sorry for my english if it is hard to understand)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
            player.SoundLocation = @"C:\Users\win7\Desktop\Sarper.wav";
            player.Play();
            Console.WriteLine("******** Make a Title ********");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Title : ");
            char[] characters= Console.ReadLine().ToUpper().ToCharArray();
            int spaces = 40 - characters.Length;

            

            
            for (int b = 0; b < spaces; b++)
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < characters.Length * 2 - 1; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("-");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int b = 0; b < spaces; b++)
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < characters.Length; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(characters[j] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int b = 0; b < spaces; b++)
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < characters.Length * 2 - 1; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("-");
            }






            Console.Read();
        }
```

Comment: Since this question is asking for code improvement, it might be better suited on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Hint: The string class has a constructor that builds a string with a character repeated the times you need https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_String__ctor_System_Char_System_Int32_

Comment: As well as all sorts of String.PadLeft...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my version: less duplication, less garbage creation (no strings immediately thrown away, no `char[]` for no reason). Though I do use `String.Join` for clarity over the `for` loop. One possible downside is `title` ends up with the entered title spaced out which might not be desirable if it is needed later.

```
Console.WriteLine("******** Make a Title ********");
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Title : ");
var title = String.Join(' ', Console.ReadLine().Select(ch => ch.ToUpper()));
var spaces = new String(' ', 40 - title.Length);
var dashes = new String('-', title.Length);

void WriteSpacedLine(string s) {
    Console.Write(spaces);
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}

WriteSpacedLine(dashes);
WriteSpacedLine(title);
WriteSpacedLine(dashes);
```

And this is a (slightly) shorter version that doesn't care so much about garbage and is (perhaps) simpler to understand:

```
Console.WriteLine("******** Make a Title ********");
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Title : ");
var title = String.Join(' ', Console.ReadLine().ToUpper().ToCharArray());
var dashes = new String('-', title.Length);

void WriteSpacedLine(string s) => Console.WriteLine(s.PadLeft(40));

WriteSpacedLine(dashes);
WriteSpacedLine(title);
WriteSpacedLine(dashes);
```

Note this code does what the original code does, and makes no attempt to center anything, it is actually right justifying against the 40 character position.

This code centers around column 40:

```
Console.WriteLine("******** Make a Title ********");
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Title : ");
var title = String.Join(' ', Console.ReadLine().ToUpper().ToCharArray());
var indent = 40 + title.Length / 2;
var dashes = new String('-', title.Length);

void WriteSpacedLine(string s) => Console.WriteLine(s.PadLeft(indent));

WriteSpacedLine(dashes);
WriteSpacedLine(title);
WriteSpacedLine(dashes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some possible improvements:

1. Instead of outputting same characters individually you can create a string that already contains the required amount of repeated characters like that: `new string(Ch, Count);`.
2. To indent strings with spaces you can use `.PadLeft(Count)`.
3. To insert spaces between characters in a string you can use `string.Join(" ", characters.ToCharArray())`.
4. Also avoid code duplication. If you see that some code is repeated try to extract and reuse it, see for example `divider` variable below.

Here is the optimized version of the code:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
    var player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer { SoundLocation = @"C:\Users\win7\Desktop\Sarper.wav" };
    player.Play();

    Console.WriteLine("******** Make a Title ********" + Environment.NewLine);
    
    Console.Write("Title : ");
    var characters = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

    var spaces = 40 - characters.Length;
    var divider = new string('-', characters.Length * 2 - 1).PadLeft(spaces);
    Console.Write(divider + Environment.NewLine +
                  string.Concat(characters.Select(ch => ch + " ")).PadLeft(spaces) + Environment.NewLine +
                  divider);

    Console.Read();
   }
```